# Creating smooth edges on a BufferedImage while using Graphics2D in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d, smoothing

I created the following code example to demonstrate my problem. I want to draw into a BufferedImage by a Graphics2D object, but the edges are not sharp. I tried using different renderinghints, but it didn't help. I also tried a BufferedImageOp as you can see in the code, but I don't understand its meaning in drawImage and don't know its possibilites. Can you help me please?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

public class SmoothGraphics extends JComponent{
    private BufferedImage image;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private int x = 100;
    private int y = 100;
    private int size = 200;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frame = new JFrame();

        SmoothGraphics component = new SmoothGraphics();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public SmoothGraphics(){
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        setBounds(100,100,400,400);
    }

    @Override 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
        image = gc.createCompatibleImage(width, height);

        Graphics2D imageGraphics = (Graphics2D) image.createGraphics();
        imageGraphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        /*imageGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);*/
        drawExample(imageGraphics);
        imageGraphics.dispose();  

        /*the following kernel helps with the smoothness of the rectangle, but not of the circle
        int kernelWidth = 3;
        int kernelHeight = 3;
        float[] data = new float[kernelWidth*kernelHeight];
        data[4]=1;
        Kernel kernel = new Kernel(kernelWidth, kernelHeight, data);
        BufferedImageOp op = new ConvolveOp(kernel);
        */
        
        //draw image
        BufferedImageOp op = null;
        g2d.drawImage(image,op,0,0);

        //I don't know if this line is necessary
        image.flush();
    }

    private void drawExample(Graphics2D g2d){
        //Square as path
        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        path.moveTo(x,y);
        path.lineTo(x+size,y);
        path.lineTo(x+size,y+size);
        path.lineTo(x,y+size);
        path.closePath();
        g2d.draw(path);

        //Circle
        g2d.fillOval(x+size/4,y+size/4,size/2,size/2);
    }
}
```

The output of my code. Notice that the edges are not very clean/sharp!
[image: The output of my code. Notice that the edges are not very clean/sharp!]

My result with antialiasing and kernel usage:

[image: My result with antialiasing and kernel usage]

My wished result:

[image: My wished result]

Comment: Did you try [VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF)?  You may also want to set [KEY_STROKE_CONTROL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#KEY_STROKE_CONTROL).

Comment: Yes I tried that. And btw isnt that the default setting? @VGR

Comment: The default settings may depend on the desktop environment itself.  For instance, text antialiasing used to be a desktop preference which end users could control. If you want to be certain, set it yourself.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "sharp edges" in this case... I suggest you post images of what you get vs what you try to achieve.

Comment: I could finally added a picture. Im sry @HaraldK but i couldnt add one earlier because im new to stack overflow.

Comment: Is that image what you get (but you want antialiasing)? Or is that what you want to achieve (but the actual result looks blurry)?

Comment: It is what i get and i tried antialiasing as rendering hint and it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... I believe the real problem you are facing is initial scaling of the component graphics (`g`), which makes your `image` stretched during `drawImage(...)`. I don't get the same problem here.

To get proper smooth (or "sharp" as you call it) rendering, you do want to enable antialiasing. But you also need to paint without pixel scaling (it's possible with image too, by creating a larger image, however, I don't see why you need the extra image in this case).

Here's your sample program rewritten:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class SmoothGraphics extends JComponent {
    private final int x = 100;
    private final int y = 100;
    private final int size = 200;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Smooth");

        SmoothGraphics component = new SmoothGraphics();
        frame.getContentPane().add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER); // Add to content pane

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack(); // Pack *before* setVisible(true)!
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame after pack()
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public SmoothGraphics() {
        setOpaque(true); // Minor optimization
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400)); // No need to use setBounds, pack() will fix that for you
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // No need to call super, as we repaint everything
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Clear background to black
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        // Paint in read, with antialiasing 
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        drawExample(g2d);
    }

    private void drawExample(Graphics2D g2d) {
        // Square (this way avoids the odd skewed lines)
        g2d.drawRect(x, y, size, size);

        // Circle
        g2d.fillOval(x + size / 4, y + size / 4, size / 2, size / 2);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Looking good, only graphics]

---

If you really want/need the `BufferedImage`, I found a way that works for me (MacOS). It might need some minor tweaks to work perfectly on other platforms.

```java
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // No need to call super, as we repaint everything
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = g2d.getDeviceConfiguration();
        AffineTransform transform = gc.getNormalizingTransform();

        BufferedImage image = gc.createCompatibleImage((int) ceil(getWidth() * transform.getScaleX()), (int) ceil(getHeight() * transform.getScaleY()));

        Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
        try {
            graphics.setTransform(transform);
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON); // Need antialiasing on 
            drawExample(graphics);
        }
        finally {
            graphics.dispose();
        }

        try {
            AffineTransform originalTransform = g2d.getTransform();
            originalTransform.concatenate(transform.createInverse());
            g2d.setTransform(originalTransform);
        } 
        catch (NoninvertibleTransformException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // API oddity, this should have been a RuntimeException
        }


        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY); // Need render QUALITY here, to avoid the stretching/tearing
//        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR); // Don't need this on MacOS, but may be needed on other platforms

        g2d.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);
    }
```

Result:

[image: Still looking good, with BufferedImage]

Comment: Thats how i got the picture of the wished result. But my problem is centered around the BufferedImage, because i want to edit a picture.

Comment: What do you think? How does the stretching occur and how could i fix it?

Comment: Added sample code with `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works even without interpolation rendering hint on my device (Windows)!